# Alamofire giving "extra argument in call" error

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to use Alamofire for a data request. Previously my code for this task without Alamofire was:

```
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

        //download hit an error so lets return out
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)

                self.image = downloadedImage
            }
        })

    }).resume()
```

And trying to use Alamofire, I tried:

```
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    Alamofire.request(.get, url)
        .responseImage { response in

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if let downloadedImage = response.result.value {
                    // image is here.
                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                    self.image = downloadedImage
                }else{
                    // check what happened.
                }
            })
    }
```

But I'm getting an error on `url` in the request parameters, "extra argument in call". I checked the other questions on the same issue here on SO and they all seemed to be trying to pass in different parameters than just a URL so I'm not sure how I can apply those answers.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Alamofire.request` parameters have changed. The first parameter used to be the HTTP method, but now the URL is the first parameter and the `method` argument is second (and is optional):

```
let url = URL(string: urlString)!    // note, unwrap the optional URL
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
    .responseImage { ... }
```

Or simply:

```
let url = URL(string: urlString)!
Alamofire.request(url)
    .responseImage { ... }
```

Or, bypass `URL` altogether:

```
Alamofire.request(urlString)
    .responseImage { ... }
```

---

Unrelated, the `DispatchQueue.main.async` is not needed with Alamofire. Unlike `URLSession`, Alamofire already runs its completion handlers on the main queue (unless you supply a `queue` parameter to `request` method). So, eliminate the `DispatchQueue.main.async` call.

Comment: Awesome, thanks man this is really helpful. Question about your second and third options though. Without specifying the method, does Alamofire just default to `.get`? Or does it notice that the parameter is a url so it reacts accordingly? And for your last option, I'm not sure how it's different than the second.. you would still have to declare the `let urlString` variable somewhere wouldn't you?

Comment: If you look at documentation or method signature for `request`, it's just the `method` parameter defaults to `.get`. Nothing fancier than that. Re the last option, my point is that your snippet suggested you had a `String` and that you were converting that to a `URL` in order to pass that to `request` method, but `request` can take either `URL` or `String`. So if you have `String`, just use that and bypass creation of separate `URL` if you want. You said "you would still have to declare the let urlString variable somewhere" ... yes, but your code snippet suggested you had already done that.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks again! As a side question, I'm wondering about the way Alamofire and AlamofireImage work together- I have both installed and imported, but commenting either of them out results in an error. Do you have to import both of them to use AlamofireImage (which is what we're using here, right?)

Comment: Yeah I added both with cocoa pods and have them both imported in the controller where I have my UIImageView extension - the code above is the only place in the project that uses it. However if I comment out the Alamofire import statement and just leave the AlamofireImage import, I get an error. Just curious why that was.

Comment: So to clarify, to use AlamofireImage (which is what I'm using in my question) one must import both Alamofire and AlamofireImage, not only AlamofireImage? Sorry if I'm not getting this...

Comment: No. If you're going to call `Alamofire.request` method, you need `import Alamofire`. If you're going to call AlamofireImage `responseImage` method, you need `import AlamofireImage`. So, with your example, you need both `import` statements. There are ways to use AlamofireImage that save you from having to use Alamofire API directly, but your example uses `request`, so you need `import Alamofire`.